# Could not get unknown property 'java' for SoftwareComponentInternal while upgrading gradle 4.5 to 5.0 and java 8 to java 11

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, multi-module

I am trying to upgrade gradle from 4.5 to gradle 5.0 and java8 to java11. I have multimodule project(backend and frontend) and root project gradle looks like below

```
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    apply plugin: 'java'
     
    def mavenArtifactId = 'root-project-name'
    group = 'com.root.project'
    
    allprojects {
        apply plugin: 'eclipse'
        version = '14.5.0-SNAPSHOT';
    ext {
        buildDate = new Date();
        productName = 'xyz'
        productDescription = 'xyz'
        gitVersion = getGitVersion();
    }
    
    if( project.hasProperty('mvn_username')) {
        mvn_user = mvn_username
    }
    if(project.hasProperty('mvn_password')) {
        mvn_pass = mvn_password
    }

    repositories {
        maven { url releaseRepo }
        maven { url snapshotRepo }
        maven { url publicRepo }
    }
}

println "Version: " + version;

def currentJvm = org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current()
println "Building with java " + currentJvm

// Define git version
def getGitVersion() {
    def describeStdOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    
    try {
        exec {
            commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags', '--always', '--dirty'
            standardOutput = describeStdOut
            ignoreExitValue true
        }
        describeStdOut.toString().trim()
    }
    catch(Exception e ) {
        "n/a"
    }
}

publish.dependsOn(':backend:test')


publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username=mvn_user
                password=mvn_pass
            }
            
            if (version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) {
                url snapshotRepo
            }
            else {
                url releaseRepo
            }
        }
    }
    
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId = mavenArtifactId 
    
            from project(':backend').components.java
            
            artifact project(':backend').javadocJar
            artifact project(':backend').sourceJar
            artifact examplePropertiesArtifact
            artifact exampleLog4jFileArtifact
            artifact windowsScriptFile
            artifact linuxScriptArtifact
            artifact aixScriptArtifact

            pom.withXml {
                asNode().appendNode('name', productName)
                asNode().appendNode('description', productDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

//wrapper {
//  gradleVersion = '5.0'
//}
```

While upgrading I am getting the error

```
Could not get unknown property 'java' for SoftwareComponentInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.
```

Please note my subproject "backend" already has java plugin in build.gradle. Similar question have found on gradle forum with no answer

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/java-11-could-not-get-unknown-property-java-for-softwarecomponentinternal/31625

Comment: You say "while upgrading": **what exactly** did you change between the last successful build and when this error message first showed up? You mention upgrading both Gradle *and* Java, which I'd discourage: pick and order and update one after the other, verifying that everything still works in between.

Comment: I just changed the gradle and java version while building the code. Also earlier I was using old eclipse and now I have moved to the new one which support java 11, so when I imported my project into recent eclipse it was not showing project in the correct format hence i used the eclipse plugin in allprojects{} to import it in correct way. 

As you suggested I moved back my java to 8 and try to build code with gradle 5 and java8 and got the same error.